# How to Program With Exchange Server 2007 (EWS) in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, wsdl, exchangewebservices

I want to call EWS in Silverlight, However I have no idea about how to call a WSDL web services in silverlight.

In a web or windows application, we can easy begin with ExchangeServiceBinding. However in Silverlight application, how could i do?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight [does not allow cross domain service calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx) which means that you probably will not be able to call EWS from your Silerlight application because they are hosted on different domains.

You might get it to work by placing a clientaccesspolicy.xml file on your Exchange Server but a better option may be to create your own WCF services hosted on the same domain as the Silverlight application.  Your Silverlight application will then call the WCF services which will call EWS in turn.

The WCF services will be a facade wrapping the calls to EWS and you will not have to call EWS directly from Silverlight.  It does require a bit of work to create the WCF services but you only have to wrap the part of EWS API that you need.